# Laravel: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Exceptions started to appear in all views, and when I try to run `composer update`, it always ends up with

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array","file":"\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php","line":188}}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

After a lot of searching and exploring each file in the 'app' folder, it appears that **one file was corrupt**

**Delete** app/storage/meta/**services.json** and re-run `composer update` and this should solve it.

Comment: Composer does not create the services.json, how do you go about this so one can be existent since I am having issues without it?

Comment: Just going to add same problem though service.json was in bootstrap/cache/

Comment: This is such a cryptic issue, hopefully others find this answer if (when) they have this symptom with Laravel.

Comment: Can't run `composer update` because of the error. (`array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`)

Comment: >>php artisan cache:clear >>php artisan config:cache >>composer update

Comment: service.json not present in Laravel 5. how can i solve it? using xamp

Comment: This happened for me by having an empty config.php file

Comment: This happened to me too and yes after doing every possible thing in the end I deleted  app/storage/meta/services.json and is working fine now. Although after running composer update it didn't regenerate this file so not sure what's happening.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes only deleting `app/storage/meta/services.json` and run `composer update` doesn't solve the ERROR: `array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array error`. At least in my case, it didn't.

Most of the time it happens when you're screwing up the `bootstrap/cache/services.json` file. And running `composer update` will not generate `services.json` file.

To generate the `services.json` file, you need to delete the previous `bootstrap/cache/services.json` file and run `php artisan serve`. Then it'll generate a fresh services.json` file.

Hope it helps to someone!

Comment: So what about when `php artisan serve` gives me the same error? (`array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`)

Comment: You've to delete the `bootstrap/cache/services.json` file first. Then try `php artisan serve`.

Comment: I don't remember what I did but it's working now. I think I made a JSON object in `services.json` with one property with the key `"providers"` or something. Although Gulp still isn't versioning my files. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I've checked with my project not available services.json in `bootstrap/cache`

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with a fresh install.

I solved it like this:
Removed `bootstrap/cache/**services.php**` and then I
surfed to the website with the browser, it generated a new services.php and then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

1. delete bootstrap folder
2. git reset --hard
3. composer install
4. done

Comment: Thanks fico7489, I cannot say whether this the best workaround but it certainly worked for me. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Mine is not fixed, after using this also, and all the other answers any idea or any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Just a `composer update` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just forgot to put compact('var') as the second return view argument

return view("path.to.view", **compact ('var')**)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue, and my problem was the version of "pusher/pusher-php-server" in composer.json was not matching with my laravel version. For this reason composer-update and deleting caches were not working for me.

I thought maybe this information could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error - "array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array error". running "composer dump-autoload" followed by npm run dev solved the problem immediately. No need of updating composer, npm etc.

Answer (score 0):

in my case app/storage/meta/services.json was empty for some reasson

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the bootstrap/cache/services.json and ran composer update after that it worked for me