# array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array after adding class into providers

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I am using pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg as soon as I installed and added the providers and alias,  it shows me the following error. This code was simply working on another machine

```
array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
```

I have tried the following things

1. Composer update/ and Fresh install
2. Cleaning the bootstrap/cache/
3. Checked the config file for laravel-ffmpeg it's there and fine
4. Publish the config file using the artisan CLI tool: php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegServiceProvider"

Here is the portion from laravel.log when I tried to run.

```
[2019-06-19 00:34:40] local.ERROR: ErrorException: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array in /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php:59
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'array_merge(): ...', '/Users/damanmok...', 59, Array)
#1 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php(59): array_merge(Array, 1)
#2 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg/src/FFMpegServiceProvider.php(25): Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider->mergeConfigFrom('/Users/damanmok...', 'laravel-ffmpeg')
#3 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(565): Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegServiceProvider->register()
#4 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php(74): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->register(Object(Pbmedia\LaravelFFMpeg\FFMpegServiceProvider))
#5 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(540): Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository->load(Array)
#6 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerConfiguredProviders()
#7 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#8 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(267): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#9 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(113): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#10 /Users/damanmokha/edetyv2/artisan(35): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 {main}
```

if I don't add these providers it works fine, but then I am not able to use ffmpeg without that.

- Laravel Version 5.3
- pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg 1.3
- php version: 7.1

Comment: check your configration file one the file return `single value` not `array` (must be send as array not single value)

Comment: Did you Publish the config file using the artisan CLI tool?

Comment: @HirenGohel yes it responds with Nothing to publish for tag [].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel: array\_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25575217/laravel-array-merge-argument-2-is-not-an-array-error)

Comment: @JigneshJoisar please check the steps, also I have tried the same answer from this question, already mentioned. but it's not helping.